# Replace the content of dictionary with another dictionary in a function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a dictionary, and I want to pass it as argument to a function. After executing this function, I want the dictionary changed.

Here is my try:

```
def func(dict):
    dict = {'a': 5}
```

So what I want to happen:

```
dict = {'b': 3}
func(dict)
print(dict) # to be {'a': 5}, not {'b': 3}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
def func(dct):
   dct.clear()
   dct.update({'a': 5})
```

Comment: when you have xxxxxxK points and you don't have time to even explain anything. Why is clear() needed? I just do `dict1.update(dict2)` and works without issues. It is needed to free up memory because the scope of the func ?

Comment: @m3nda -- You could try it out and see :).  It isn't a memory issue.  It's an API issue.   OP wanted the existing key `'b'` to disappear.  If you don't clear the dictionary first, the existing keys that aren't in the update dictionary will still persist.

Answer (score 7):

You can *mutate* a dictionary within a method, because it is passed by reference, but in your case you're simply creating a new dictionary altogether. Since your variable `dict` is within a method, it doesn't share the same scope as the outer contents, and so refers to a new variable. If you want to overwrite it altogether, consider:

```
def func(dct):
    return {'a': 5}

dct = func(dct)
```

The only benefit that I can see from completely wiping an existing dictionary and updating it with new content is if it had multiple other references which you *also* wished to update. If this isn't the case I'd suggest you just create a new dictionary. If the old dictionaries ref count drops to zero then it'll be garbage collected, so I don't see any great memory benefits.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP question. And it is a legitimate question, there a sometime when rewriting a dict inplace is necessary and the new value doesnt have to be a constant like in OP question. For example when the function that writes the new value doesn't know where the dict comes from and the dict might belong to a list or be an attribute of something.
Also you wrote "dct = {'a': 5}" using 3 lines and a function assign. Not great.